# How to change UniformInt64 partition count and partition low/high key without redeploying the service dynamically?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

Hi I have a stateless service partitioned using **UniformInt64** kind, Is there a way to change the **partition count**, **high/low key** on the fly without re-deploying the service? I see, with powershell command we can change the Instance count but I didnt find a way to update **partition count** and **low/high key** using same.

Answer (score 2):

You can't change partitions on the fly. To remove or add partitions, would require all stored data in all partitions to be re-partitioned. There's no support for this in SF.

To deal with this, you can introduce an intermediate service to act as sort of a 'librarian' when you need to fetch or store data.
[Here's a video](https://youtu.be/fN9zQm_FVVw) that explains more about partitioning and the librarian service.

More docs about partitioning [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-concepts-partitioning) and a really good blog post [here](http://henidak.com/2015/07/service-fabric-partitions/).

Comment: I think there is a work around, we can use application parameters to change partition configuration, but I have not tested it. Will try and let you know. Thanks